# Animating GridView in android

Tags: android, gridview, animation

I have a grid view (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).
Can i animate these images, like moving up,down,left right. Think those images are balls and i want to animate those balls.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several examples of animating GridViews in the android [List of Samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html).

You can build this right from Eclipse. Go to File > New > Android Project. Select Create Project from existing sample, and be sure to specify a api level.